# Why can we see not pointlike but extended objects on the sky?

Tags: cosmology

Strictly speaking, our past light-cone allows us to observe light emitted by pointlike events situated on a conical two-dimensional surface around us and extending back in time, as is well illustrated in comoving coordinates. But how is it then possible to see an extended large three-dimensional object like a galaxy on the sky at one glance?

Comment: I would think that image of the galaxy is smeared out in time as well, but it takes hundreds of millions or even billions of years for visible changes to effect over the many thousands of light years that span an entire galaxy which is much longer than the time it takes for light to cross the depth or width of a galaxy.

Comment: Here's a question (from a few months ago) on this topic on our sister site: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/43739/16685

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, processes which operate on point-like sources can be integrated using calculus to describe the effects that occur from distributed sources.

Also, it can be elucidate to take a step back and consider how an image is formed by a classical lens. While the story isn't quite the same, there are many "how can this happen" which can start by looking at a lens and asking how it happens in a non-relativistic environment first, and then extend it to the relativistic one.

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly write, our past light cone has two spatial coordinates. That's the celestial sphere on which we see objects. So already there it's clear that we don't just see point-like objects, but their two-dimensional projections on that celestial sphere.

Putting yourself in the center of spherical coordinates, the celestial sphere makes the two angles, and the time dimension can be thought of as the third radial coordinate. And indeed if an object is in the way, you can in general *not* look past it.

In addition to this more philosophical aspect, in reality, distances e.g. to galaxies are far compared to the extend of these galaxies themselves. So the light from the "left" and "right" side of the galaxy enter your eyes at basically the same time, to a very, *very* good approximation. Similarly, if you e.g. use an infrared telescope to look past a dust cloud in a far-away galaxy, you can see the young stars behind it, but given the distances involved, that light was emitted at essentially the same time as well.

So in that sense it is as you write: We can only see the universe in an instant of time. Using your language, the point-like-ness refers to the time slice, not to the angle on the sky.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question best. Before asking the question I came to the same conclusion by drawing the light-cone diagram and the projection on the sky , but I wanted a confirmation because I had to think about spherical hypersurfaces. Effectively, the light-cone shell has zero spatial depth. The coordinates on the sky are AR and declination and the depth in space is measured by the cosmological redshift z, i.e. z observed  = z expansion on the past lightcone. And this is all the way how redshift surveys are done! Greetings from Switzerland   RK

Comment: exactly. I help myself routinely by reducing the three spacial coordinates to just one. In that sense the light-cone doesn't have "zero spatial depth" but still is one dimension on paper out of the three in reality.